# Opening Arduino Pin in OUTPUT mode from Python

Tags: python, arduino, binary, serial-port, arduino-uno

TLDR: I wanted to drive hardware with Python, and thought I'd need Arduino to get the job done. Turns out I could get the job done without Arduino at all, so the post below is strictly nonsense.

---

I am looking to interface with my first Arduino Uno board and would like to use Python for the task. I'm wondering if someone could help me convert a simple bit of Arduino / C to Python for the task. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the block I'm looking at:

```
#include <Wire.h>

// control pin
int txden = 8;

// data prefix and suffix
byte data_prefix[] = {0x80, 0x83, 0xFF};
byte data_suffix[] = {0x8F};

// 28 bytes
byte all_dark[] = {
  B0000000, B0000000, B0000000, B0000000,
  B0000000, B0000000, B0000000, B0000000,
  B0000000, B0000000, B0000000, B0000000,
  B0000000, B0000000, B0000000, B0000000,
  B0000000, B0000000, B0000000, B0000000,
  B0000000, B0000000, B0000000, B0000000,
  B0000000, B0000000, B0000000, B0000000,                   
};

byte word_to_display[] = {
  B0000000, B0000000, B0101110, B0101010,
  B0111010, B0000000, B0000000, B0100010,
  B0101010, B0111110, B0000000, B0000000,
  B0000010, B0000010, B0111110, B0000000,
  B0000000, B0111110, B0000010, B0111110,
  B0000000, B0000000, B0010110, B0101000,
  B0101000, B0111110, B0000000, B0000000
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  pinMode(txden, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(txden, HIGH);
  Serial.write(data_prefix, 3);
  Serial.write(all_dark, 28);
  Serial.write(data_suffix, 1);
  delay(3000);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.write(data_prefix, 3);
  Serial.write(word_to_display, 28);
  Serial.write(data_suffix, 1);
  delay(2000);  
}
```

The Arduino IDE first interprets the `setup` function, then continuously runs the `loop` function, as a game engine (e.g. Phaser) does. `Serial.write` sends binary data outward through a serial port to my flipdot display, and the flipdots interpret that message and react accordingly.

The loop above displays on the flipdots board:

[image]

I'm under the impression the `pyserial` package may allow me to send the same bytes through the same pin. Here's as far as I've gotten:

```
import serial

# serial: https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial.html#overview

# args: device, bauds, timeout -- baud timeout must be exact
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=.1)

data_prefix = bytearray([0x80, 0x83, 0xFF])

data_suffix = bytearray([0x8F])

all_dark = bytearray([
  0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000,
  0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000,
  0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000,
  0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000,
  0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000,
  0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000,
  0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0000000,
])

word_to_display = bytearray([
  0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0101110, 0B0101010,
  0B0111010, 0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0100010,
  0B0101010, 0B0111110, 0B0000000, 0B0000000,
  0B0000010, 0B0000010, 0B0111110, 0B0000000,
  0B0000000, 0B0111110, 0B0000010, 0B0111110,
  0B0000000, 0B0000000, 0B0010110, 0B0101000,
  0B0101000, 0B0111110, 0B0000000, 0B0000000,
])
```

I need to figure out how I can open pin 8 on the Arduino in OUTPUT mode from Python. Once that's sorted, I also need to figure out how to replicate the [`setup`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/sketch/setup/) and [`loop`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/sketch/loop/) functions and their constituent calls now, including the [`Serial.write()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/) method, which writes binary data to a serial port for interpretation by the flipdot device. Any pointers would be super helpful.

Comment: Programs on an MCU have some differences from programs on a CPU. In your case the `loop()` runs continuously which is fine on a MCU but not desirable on a CPU since it would occupy one CPU core by 100%. You can still run your code in a loop, but make sure it releases the CPU from time to time. This can be done by code that awaits I/O or with `time.sleep()` and a short interval.

Comment: On what platform you are want to run python? Arduino? or a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I have to use Arduino at the moment. If there's a way to specify the same baud rate and `pinMode` on a Raspberry Pi I'm happy to use that instead as I have more familiarity. But I feel this should be accomplishable in Python. But how can I open pin 8 in OUTPUT mode from Python on Arduino?

Comment: For running python on Arduino, you need [micro-python](http://micropython.org) or [circuit python](https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython), it has the commands designed for handling the GPIO configuration that you see in the setup() code, for the code in the loop(), you should be able to do it with a `while(1) {...}` together with the pySerial that you already use.

Comment: But honestly I don't understand why you need to port the code to run under python.

Comment: @hcheung my ultimate goal is to take an incoming stream of video, binarize it to a x,y pixel display, and use the dots to display that stream. I just thought I'd be better at accomplishing this in Python than in Arduino, which I've never used before. But if there are helpers to accomplish this specific task in Arduino I'm happy to use that syntax!

Comment: Maybe he wants to upload Firmata firmware on UNO and then use pyFirmata to send commands from python program to be executed on UNO. But it won't do anything without python program running on the computer

Comment: Or maybe he wants single ftdi (or any other USB/serial module) and just use DTR to control txden pin?

Comment: I guess which language to use is depend on the familiarity to the language. C++ has complete standard library for handling array too. BTW, what you are trying to do is something similar to writing a display driver. I happened to have a LCD driver written both in python (for [RPI](https://github.com/e-tinkers/LCD-5110-Raspberry-Library) and in c++(for [Arduino](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2017/11/how-to-use-lcd-5110-pcd-8544-with-arduino/), both are functionally identical. Hope it will give you some ideas and see the differences/similarities between Python and C++.

Comment: I think OP has some fundamental misunderstanding about what Arduino does.  If you just want to control the display with a serial signal then you don’t need the Arduino at all, just send commands on a serial interface to the display.  It would be easier from an Arduino but then you have to write the code on an Arduino.  If you want to do something from python then you’ll need to also write code on the arduino to accept the data from the PC and echo it out on a second serial interface.  It isn’t really clear what the point of this exercise is so it’s really hard to help here.

Comment: I just want to drive the flipdot display from Python so that I can use computer vision / machine learning resources in Python to change the display. I think @Delta_G is totally right, I don't need Arduino at all--I just need to send binary data through a CPU serial port to the display. I was thinking of Arduino as something magical, but now I see it as a little device that does something I could do with a normal CPU or Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm under the impression the pyserial package may allow me to send the
> same bytes through the same pin.

pyserial will let you send data out a serial interface.  It has nothing to do with Arduino.  If all you want is for this serial data to go to your display then there's no need for Arduino at all.  Just connect your serial lines to the display and send serial data directly from the PC.

> I also need to figure out how to replicate the setup and loop
> functions

That's very simple.  Write the code that you want to run once first, and then put the code that you want run in an infinite loop into an infinite loop.  while(1) works well to create an infinite loop.  There's nothing special about setup or loop functions on Arduino.  They're just regular functions that get called from the main function.  setup gets called once and then loop gets called in an infinite loop.

It really isn't clear why you think you need to involve an Arduino here.  If it is simply that you don't know how to connect things to a PC then perhaps a Raspberry Pi would be a better choice as it can both run python and has GPIO pins that you can connect things to.  A second option would be to load firmata on the Arduino and use pyFirmata from python to control that.  You can google both of those terms, there are lots of tutorials on how to do that.

I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings about what an Arduino does.  Perhaps it would do you some good to spend some time away from this project learning some of the basics and then return to this once you have some experience and a little bit of understanding about what all of these things mean.

The larger question is why do you want to involve python?  Is there a reason it needs to be controlled from a PC?  Or is it just that you don't want to learn a new language?  Those are two very different issues that would promt me to give you very different responses.  If you need to be able to control the display from a PC then just do that and use your Arduino for something else later.

Comment: Yes, I think this is right. I need to connect pins to the cpu and open those pins to send data to the display, or just use a Pi and send the data from the Pi to the display. The reason for Python is just that I'll be much faster with the computer vision tasks that will eventually be included in the pipeline.